# Read alternative name from certificate

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, x509

I want to write a code that read the *User Principal Name* from the *Other names* under *Subject Alternative* name from a certificate.

I have an X509Certificate.

I did (certificate is X509Certificate object):

```
Collection san = certificate.getSubjectAlternativeNames()
```

How can I get the User principal name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it
http://svn.eparapher.com/trunk/org.eparapher.core/src/main/java/org/eparapher/core/crypto/cert/CertificateInfo.java